# AWS fargate unable to delete cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I'm practising the creation of AWS fargate cluster, after couple of trial and error I decided to delete my cluster and recreated it from zero, but I get the error:

`Unable to delete cluster XXXXXXX, 
Deletion of CloudFormation stack timed out.`

Then if I go to CloudFormation I can see:

`Stack name: XXXX
Delete Failed`

After I checked the events for that CloudFormation stack and it seems to fail because it can delete the VPC:

`The following resource(s) failed to delete: [Vpc].`

I can tell that I have not running tasks that might prevent someone to delete a cluster.

I was expecting that AWS take care of deleting everything that was created for that fargate cluster.

Does anyone else have faced this issue?, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself:

I have deleted manually the VPC, which was the thing preventing CloudFormation to delete the stack that create the ECS Fargate cluster, after re-run the delete within the cluster in question, and after that the cluster got deleted.

In addition I have to delete the "tasks definition created" for AWS fargate manually by deregistering them, thanks.